# How to integrate PHPUnit with zend framework or any other custom php framework?

Tags: php, phpunit

How to integrate PHPUnit with [PHP Pro custom php framework](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)?

I need how to get the framework environment just how we get in Zend Framework.

There are tons of tutorials available for Zend but not for custom framework like PHP Pro

Also PHPUnit does not give example with MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially for the Zend Framework there is [Zend_Test](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.html) mentioned at the manual.

Comment: There is usually no real difference against using PHPUnit for standalone classes, except that Units, which depends on frameworks, often needs some setup before they are usable. You can define a bootstrap for PHPUnit to specify a global setup and you can use Fixtures (http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/fixtures.html) to make sure the Units are ready to get tested.

Comment: I guess there no tutorial available for PHPunit integration with custom framework. The tutorials are vailable for Zend framework and symfony primarily. 
I need a tutorial that will set up PHPunit for my framework and i can test my controllers by manipulating the POST or GET array, so that i can check whether the underlying functionalities like Uer registration, Group creation work properly and secondly what if my controllers i have ajax request in them ? 

OR
I have to use selenium to do the testing? 
What is the use of phpunit and Selenium together ?